# Apache ProxyPass with SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, proxypass

I want to proxy requests from an SSL site via a non-SSL site. My Apache httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName foo.com
    ProxyPass / https://bar.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

So, when I visit http://foo.com, I expect apache to make a request to https://bar.com and send me the the page it fetched.

Instead, I get a 500 error, and in the error log, I see:

```
[error] proxy: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 4.3.2.1:443 (bar.com)
```

Presumably I'm missing a directive here. Which might it be?

**Never mind the security implications. I fully understand the risks.**

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using?

Comment: "Never mind the security implications. I fully understand the risks." - This is the devops equivalent of "Hold My Beer" ; )

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You'll need `mod_ssl`, `mod_proxy` and optionally `mod_rewrite`. Depending on your distribution and Apache version you may have to check if `mod_proxy_connect` and `mod_proxy_http` are loaded as well.

The directives for enabling SSL proxy support are in mod_ssl:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName foo.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
    ProxyPass / https://secure.bar.com
    ProxyPassReverse / https://secure.bar.com
</VirtualHost>
```

IIRC you can also use:

```
    RewriteRule / https://secure.bar.com [P]    # don't forget to setup SSLProxy* as well
```

Comment: With SSLProxy* directives, works as a charm

Answer (score 2):

In Apache 1.x, `mod_ssl` would fix up ProxyPass.  Do you have `mod_ssl` installed?