# SSL mod_proxy issues in <location> bracket

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I am having trouble with getting proxypass to work in apache.

My configuration file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.org
    ServerAdmin info@example.org
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/knyz.org/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/knyz.org/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/knyz.org/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/knyz.org/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/knyz.org.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/knyz.org.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/knyz.org.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/knyz.org/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        SSLRequireSSL
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/knyz.org/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.knyz.org.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.knyz.org.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.knyz.org.ca
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        RGroups www-data
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/sapache2.knyz.org.conf*

    ##ISSUE IS HERE!!!
    <Location /admin>
        ProxyPass https://localhost:8083
        ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8083
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Desired result:
The page from localhost on port 8083 will be shown when accessing the `/admin` subdirectory.

Actual result: Error 500

The issue seems to be the same as here: [Apache ProxyPass with SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/84821/apache-proxypass-with-ssl)

Except the solution does not work for me.

When attempting to do so, I get the following error while restarting apache:

`SSLProxyEngine not allowed here`

From error logs (concerning error 500):

```
[Sun Dec 13 21:33:31.062959 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 1181] [remote 127.0.0.1:8083] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for example.org:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Sun Dec 13 21:33:31.063033 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 1181] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 127.0.0.1:8083 (localhost)
```

How can I fix this issue?

## Update

I replaced the location block with the following

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /blog http://127.0.0.1:2368/blog
  ProxyPassReverse /blog http://127.0.0.1:2368/blog
  ProxyPass /admin https://127.0.0.1:8083
  ProxyPassReverse /admin https://127.0.0.1:8083
```

And now `/blog` works properly but `/admin` DOES NOT. This means that the issue is definitely with the SSL.

Comment: @ekaj I happened to test what you proposed even before seeing your answer ;) Anyways updated question. Issue must be with HTTPS

Comment: Note: My setup is configured as such that I am forced to use https on port 8083

Comment: @ekaj SSLProxyEngine On did the trick. Also yes everything is setup as intended. It's a bit of a weird setup but it works the way I need it to.

Comment: @ekaj Want to write an answer with SSLProxyEngine so I can close the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell ProxyPass isn't meant to be used inside of a block - you have it in a `<Location>` block. It needs to be out of that block, and you need to turn `SSLProxyEngine` on as well:

```
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass /admin https://localhost:8083/
    ProxyPassReverse /admin https://localhost:8083/
```